# React Navigation, navigate out of nested navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have navigator (`X`) which holds a screen, lets call it `N`, and another navigator, `Y`. I need to travel from a screen in navigator `Y`, to screen `N` in the root navigator. How would I go about doing this using react navigation 6?

Code for the root router:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tabs.Navigator>
    <Tabs.Screen component={HomeRouter} name="HomeTab" />
  </Tabs.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Code for Home router (Navigator `X`):

```
<NavigationContainer independent={true}>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"Home"}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Post" component={Post} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Account} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Code for profile router (Navigator `Y`):

```
<NavigationContainer independent={true} theme={MyTheme}>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="MainProfile" component={MainAccountPage} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

I need to navigate from the `MainAccountPage` screen in `navigator Y` to the `Post` screen in `navigator X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. General overview

Say we have those nested navigators, notice that there is only one `NavigationContainer` for all of them:

```js
function Home() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

If you're calling `navigation.goBack()` in a nested screen, it'll only go back in the parent navigator if you're already on the first screen of the nested navigator. Other actions such as `navigate` work similarly, i.e. navigation will happen in the nested `navigator`, and if the nested navigator couldn't handle it, then the parent navigator will try to handle it.

As an example, when calling `navigate('Messages')` inside `Feed` screen, the nested tab navigator will handle it, but if you call `navigate('Settings')`, the parent stack navigator will handle it.

## 2. Solution to the question

First of all you should have one single `NavigationContainer` for all your nested navigators, which means the `Y` navigator should be like this instead :

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="MainProfile" component={MainAccountPage} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

After that, as `MainAccountPage` is used as a screen, you get the `navigation` object from React Navigation in the `props`. You could navigate this way (put the line where you need):

```js
export default function MainAccountPage({navigation}){
  navigation.navigate("Post"); // how you navigate
  return <></>
}
```